# Loop over a list in python and create a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list "profiles" looking like this for each element of the list: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu1lE.png)

I want to create a dataframe out of this list, so that every account is in the dataframe.
When I create one dataframe for every element of the list manually and then append them all to one dataframe it works. However, I wanted to do a loop because I have about 40 elements in that list.

The code looks as follows (doing it manually):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(profiles[1])
df1 = df1.append(df2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(profiles[2])
df1 = df1.append(df3)
... and so on
```

My loop looks like this:

```
   for y in range(len(profiles)):
        if x != y:
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(profiles[x])
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(profiles[y])
            df1.append(df2)
```

Does anybody know how to make the loop work? Because it does not append the second dataframe.

Comment: some links for reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, `df.append` is deprecated from version 1.4.0, so it's better to use `df.concatenate`. Also, if possible, please add a data sample for us to try out and your exptected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting your df1 in each iteration of the loop

IIUC, In the absence of the reproducible data and example, this is what you should add to your code

outside of the for loop, create an empty dataframe

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
```

inside the loop

```
df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df1], axis=1)
```

if your df1 and df2 both gets initialized in each iteration, then you can add them both to the df_final together as follows

```
df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df1, df2], axis=1)
```

at the end of the loop df_final will have all the df's appended to it

Answer (score 0):

append is not an inPlace Operation, so you have to assign the result of the function (otherwise it gets lost)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).